# Workflow starts for some people but not others?

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow

I have a workflow that starts off in a 2013 workflow, inserts info into another list which is a 2010 workflow and finishes fine when I make the initial entry into a form. One of my co-workers, though, makes an entry but the workflow does not kick off. Has anyone heard of this? Is it just a permissions issue?

Comment: Yes, possible permission issue. You need to click the exclamation mark to see details of why workflow is suspended.

Comment: If you are the author of workflow, add App step in 2013 workflow instead of regular step. You will have to manage one site feature before publishing this workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , this might be a permission issue for the user who is trying to start the workflow , to start the workflow in a SharePoint List/Library item the user needs

- **Edit Items** permissions to start a workflow.
- Some workflows may require that you also have the **Manage Lists
  permission**, or another specific permission, to start a workflow on
  a document or item.

Please make sure that the user has these required permission on the respective list or Library.